# Запятые в обороте "ну(,) а что..."

Tags: пунктуация

Имеется такое предложение: "Ну(,) а что(,) кот (—) не человек, что ли?" Интересует правильность расстановки знаков препинания, взятых в скобки. Подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы запятые оставил, а тире - нет, так как между подлежащим и сказуемым, выраженными существительными, стоит частица НЕ

Answer (score 0):

Согласен с Виктором, только запятая после ***ну***, на мой взгляд не нужна. Это скорее частица, чем междометие.